# python crawl question : how to get text in <B></B>

Tags: python, pycharm, web-crawler

I have some problems with learning python crawl.
I want to get text inside  tags.

Page source code as follow:

```
<td><B>Kings Trailer</B></td>
```

need result is:

```
Kings Trailer
```

How can i do this?
Thank you for reading and helping.

Answer (score 0):

```
pageSource.find('B').getText()
```

Not sure what B is but i think this will work

Comment: Thanks! for your attention. but it doesn't work. I tried "soup.find_all('B')", that can display "<B>Kings Trailer</B>", i will find some ways to delete B.

Comment: You can use split(‘>’)…